# Eliminate doesn't work

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-calculus, algebra

I tried to define r by the polynomials a,b,c only. The result which I want is r=4/3 a.
But this eliminate doesn't work! It is continue running without stop and without any output.

Eliminate[{a == x[1] x[2]^3 + x[2] x[3]^3 + x[3] x[1]^3,
b == 5 x[1]^2 x[2]^2 x[3]^2 - x[1]^5 x[2] - x[2]^5 x[3] - x[3]^5 x[1],
c == x[1]^14 + x[2]^14 + x[3]^14 - 34 (x[1]^11 x[2] x[3]^2 - x[1]^2 x[2]^11 x[3] -  x[1] x[2]^2 x[3]^11) - 250 (x[1]^9 x[2]^4 x[3] - x[1]^1 x[2]^9 x[3]^4 - x[1]^4 x[2]^1 x[3]^9) + 375 (x[1]^8 x[2]^2 x[3]^4 - x[1]^4 x[2]^8 x[3]^2 - x[1]^2 x[2]^4 x[3]^8) + 18 (x[1]^7 x[2]^7 + x[2]^7 x[3]^7 + x[1]^7 x[3]^7) -  126 (x[1]^6 x[2]^5 x[3]^3 - x[1]^3 x[2]^6 x[3]^5 - x[1]^5 x[2]^3 x[3]^6),
r == 4/3 (x[1] x[2]^3 + x[1]^3 x[3] + x[2] x[3]^3)}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}]

Comment: `GroebnerBasis` is much faster here. `In[20]:= polys = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];
Timing[elimpoly = 
  First[GroebnerBasis[polys, {r, a, b, c}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]]]

Out[21]= {0.012268, -4 a + 3 r}`

Comment: `Solve[eqns, {a, b, c, r}, {x[1], x[2], x[3]}] // Timing ` is also very fast, but much easier to understand for non-polynomial-experts.

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Akku14. I really appreciate your replies. It works in the given polynomials but stuck again in another one in the ring  of [ a,b,c].